# Cancel request in google ajax api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-ajax-api

I'm doing small AJAX searchbar with "new google.search.WebSearch();" from Google AJAX Api.

How do i can cancel an ongoing ajax request?

I usually do a:

```
var xhr;
function Something() {
xhr.stop();
xhr = $.get ....
}
```

in jQuery.

What is the equavalent for the Google websearch object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the Google AJAX API, but this page shows a method called `.cancelSearch()`. Maybe what you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_GSearchControl